# The "right" way of dynamic pages (Query Strings, URLs)

Tags: php, html, database, dynamic

I have 2 questions i've been curious about.

1. I've seen query strings as a way of creating dynamic pages, by passing a variable between, the .php page can then follow it up by retrieving content based on that string. Is query string the BEST and most COMMON way to do dynamic websites?
2. With some URI, you see the following

**www.website.com/somepage.php?query_string**

but some other pages you see a very clean

**www.website.com/pages/posts/101/title_of_page.**

What is it that makes the URI clean without showing the actual query?

A very simple explanation would be awesome, or a website that can describe this. Many thanks.

Comment: I want to say yes and `mod_rewrite` (apache mod) does the clean URLs.

Comment: nothing wrong with the original version, so called *clean* urls are a fad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is a *SEO-friendly* URL.  These days, unless you have requirements that don't allow you to leverage them, that's the approach to go with.  Pretty much all modern CMSs leverage SEO-friendly URLs.

Translating a SEO-friendly URL to a query string is handled by [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  This is typically handled in your site's `vhost` configuration, or can be handled in `.htaccess` files.  The latter is less efficient however and is discouraged by Apache.

Comment: you just flamed me for saying `.htaccess` then edit your post about how to use them ???

Comment: I did not *flame* you @Cjueden. I simply pointed out that `.htaccess` *does not rewrite URLs*.  `mod_rewrite` does.  Do you see the difference?

Comment: I understand `mod_rewrite` but if OP doesn't know about or how to use `.htacces` OP can't do much with `mod_rewrite` I was thinking along the lines of walk before you run.

Comment: @Cjueden I didn't downvote you.  I gave you feedback. You're fairly new here - when someone gives you feedback consider editing your answer.  That's what the edit button is there for.  I understand your "walk before you run" comment, but linking to docs on `.htaccess` won't *at all* help op understand how to rewrite URLs.  So your answer is, at best, incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

Clean URL's are actually masked query strings, called "pretty permalinks". Most times this is done with the `.htaccess` file and `mod_rewrite`; something like:

```
RewriteRule pages/(.+) somepage.php/?page=$1 [QSA,L,B]
```

Comment: That `RewriteRule` is awfully lax without any anchors.

Comment: Bet you a taco op will copy/paste that code and just replace the tokens with what he/she needs. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What is it that makes the URI clean without showing the actual query?

`.htaccess`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: `.htaccess` doesn't rewrite URLs, what's more `.htaccess` is a relatively inefficient approach to handling requests